# CodeEval challenge: Grid Walk

Tags: c#, java, c++

There is a challenge from CodeEval, called Grid Walk.

Programming language doesn't really matter.

I've tried to crack it down, and I thought I did, as the answers my program gave me to smaller numbers (9 and 10) were correct according to an on-paper drawing.

As my program says, the final result should be 111005, but CodeEval doesn't seem to agree with that.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?
What is the correct answer? A hint?

The [challenge](http://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/60/):

> There is a monkey which can walk around on a planar grid. The monkey
>   can move one space at a time left, right, up or down. That is, from
>   (x, y) the monkey can go to (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), and (x,
>   y-1). Points where the sum of the digits of the absolute value of the
>   x coordinate plus the sum of the digits of the absolute value of the y
>   coordinate are lesser than or equal to 19 are accessible to the
>   monkey. For example, the point (59, 79) is inaccessible because 5 + 9
>   + 7 + 9 = 30, which is greater than 19. Another example: the point (-5, -7) is accessible because abs(-5) + abs(-7) = 5 + 7 = 12, which
>   is less than 19. How many points can the monkey access if it starts at
>   (0, 0), including (0, 0) itself?

And a picture of where my program thinks the monkey can walk (green areas),
going from -298 to 298 in both X and Y axis, (0,0) being the center.

[image: NotSolution]

**UPDATE:**

I have the solution now. As I was building the points through the axis, I demanded that the previous y or the previous x were good, so this made me lose all the extra unreachable locations, leaving me with this, the right amount: 102485

[image: Solution]

Comment: It may be that your program computes all valid points but the challenge asks for all accessible points. It may be the case that many valid points are not accessible (i.e., they may be behind a point that is not accessible and there is no other way to get there, such as diagonal movements).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but my program calculates accessible points only. You can see the update for a picture of what my program thinks the reachable zone looks like.

Comment: Are green the accessible points? In that case there are many accessible point which are not visitable by the monkey when starting at (0, 0). Have you exluded these from your final count?

Comment: The problem would be how to identify those areas in the most efficient way? Also, I was wondering whether it is possible to come out with a formula for this problem, because it's all so symmetrical and mathematical looking, it might just have a complicated formula, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a flood-fill from (0,0) on the shape you've found, and you get all the points accessible from (0,0).

Comment: Could you elaborate? I can imagine what that is, but what would be the best way to do it? Also, the picture was just to illustrate the situation to myself and you guys. I hope I could disregard unreachable areas as I go through the axis. (I think I have the solution in hand. I'm testing it)

Comment: You were in the right direction and the only answerer, so you got the credit ;) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @YoryeNathan Haha, you had done everything right, just needed to incorporate the fact that the monkey needs to be able to walk to each square.